# Condition for set of de Rham cohomology classes is linearly independent

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

If we have a set of 1-forms $w_1, ... w_n$ on a smooth manifold $X$ I can show that $w_i$ are linearly dependent if and only if $w_1 \wedge ... \wedge w_n = 0$.

I wondered if this is also true in the cohomology $H(X)$ using the product induced from the wedge product. Namely is it true that cohomology classes $[w_i]$ are linearly dependent if and only if:

$$[w_1][w_2]...[w_n] = [0]$$

I tried to prove this using the same method as for differential 1-forms. If the classes are linearly dependent then we can write $[w_1] = \sum c_i [w_i]$ and then terms like $[w_2][w_2][w_3]...[w_n]$ are the zero class because $w'_2 \wedge w''_2$ will be exact ($w'$ some representatives for $[w_2]$) and then the whole wedge product will be exact because the cohomology classes are closed.

I'm struggling to show the other direction, namely if $[w_1][w_2]...[w_n] = [0]$ are the classes linearly dependent in $H(X)$? I'm not even sure if it is true.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p_1,p_2\}$. You have $H^1$ of rank 2 spanned by $w_1,w_2$ and $H^2=0$ so that $w_1w_2=0$.

Comment: This is already false for every closed surface of positive genus.

Comment: You seem to have independence and dependence muddled throughout!

Comment: @TedShifrin  Apologies for that - I've fixed it now!

Comment: @MikeMiller In a torus do we not have the 1 forms $d \theta_i$ forming a basis for the cohomology with $d \theta_1 \wedge ... \wedge d \theta_n$ non-zero?

Comment: Misspoke. "Genus greater than one."

Comment: Ah I see okay - how do we know that?